# "behavior" gets an article while being single?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Does the word "behavior" get an article while being single?

The context is: 
Do these changes make (a) negative behavior or (a) positive behavior?

Comment: Your entire construction is weird. I suspect you mean something like "Do these changes promote positive or negative behavior?" Note that *behavior* can be a count noun or a mass noun, depending on the context.

Comment: My mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: Well, *make* is still the wrong verb there. It's totally non-idiomatic in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "make" behavior. You need to use the phrasal verb [*make for*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-for):

> 2. *phrasal verb*
>      If something **makes for** another thing, it causes or helps to cause that thing to happen or exist.

So your example should be:

> Do these changes **make for** negative or positive behavior?

You could use "a" for emphasis, but *behavior* in general isn't countable.